# How to get restrictions for datetimepicker delphi

Tags: delphi

I got a datetimepicker. It saves it into the database but it is possible to select date before current date. Is there a way to stop that? to only let to select from present day and further?

thanks in advance

Jasper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `MinDate` property of the TDateTimePicker instance to the current date.

```
DateTimePicker1.MinDate := Date();
```

Comment: yep that did it :), I couldnt find it anywhere, thx for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker1.MinDate := Yesterday();